# Frenet equations used in curved space

Tags: differential-geometry

I've been reading [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.0264) article by M. Abramowicz. Very interesting article but I can't make sense of one detail:  the author writes Eq.$(9)$ stating that we can use (that) Frenet equation to define the variation of the tangent vector along one of the concentric circles (please read the article from subsection $2$). The thing is the [Frenet equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas) are only valid in case of a differentiable curve in the 3-dimensional Euclidean space (right)? So how can the author use the Frenet equation? Is he considering that the surface is embedded in an 3-dimensional Euclidean space?